# Cannot find module error while doing docker build error TS2307: Cannot find module 'Joi' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying dockerise my Node js app simply using a `Dockerfile`.
The app runs perfectly in local machine and gets build but while I try to dockerise it I am getting the below error for the package Joi.

**Cannot find module 'Joi' or its corresponding type declarations.**

Sharing my `Dockerfile`, `.dockerignore` and `package.json`.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:20-alpine as dependencies
# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files to /app
COPY package.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code to /app
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Expose port 5000
EXPOSE 5000

# Start the server
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

`.dockerignore`

```
.git
node_modules
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "Platform_user",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/devarshiroy93/Platform_user.git",
  "author": "devarshiroy93 <devarshiroy93@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node dist/index.js\" "
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.5",
    "prisma": "^5.8.1",
    "tsc-watch": "^6.0.4",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "schema": "src/infrastructure/db/prisma/schema.prisma"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.8.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "joi": "^17.12.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: To confirm, it's the `RUN npm build` step in the Dockerfile that's having the problem?  What does the actual Typescript code look like?  You don't seem to have included the `package-lock.json` file in the image; is it possible you're getting different Javascript packages on the host and container that are leading to problems?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes it the ```RUN npm build``` build step that is breaking. I have changed my dockerfile to include package-lock.json as well.Still getting the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you might have something like this in one of your source files:

```
import Joi from 'Joi';
```

The package name is case sensitive, so you need to use `joi` rather than `Joi`.

```
import Joi from 'joi';
```

Here's a working project that uses your `Dockerfile` and `package.json`.

```
├── Dockerfile
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── index.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

`index.ts`

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import Joi from 'joi';

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send('Hello, world!');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

[image]